# Getting scroll index from scrolling position in pixels listview flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, scrollcontroller

Is there a way we can use **ScrollController.position.pixels** to know the scrolling index of a listview in flutter? I'm trying to restore the last scrolling index between app restarts.

Comment: Does your  `Listview` item have the same height?  You like to save scrollPosition on phone storage?

Comment: No.. list item has different height. I'd like to save index in shared preferences which I can retrieve later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flutter_scrollview_observer](https://github.com/LinXunFeng/flutter_scrollview_observer) lib to implement your desired functionality without invasivity

Create and use instance of `ListView` normally.

```dart
ListView _buildListView() {
  return ListView.separated(
    ...
  );
}
```

Pass the `ListView` instance to the `ListViewObserver`, then you can obtain the desired result in the `onObserve` callback

```dart
ListViewObserver(
  child: _buildListView(),
  onObserve: (resultModel) {
    print('firstChild.index -- ${resultModel.firstChild?.index}');
    print('displaying -- ${resultModel.displayingChildIndexList}');
  },
)
```